# Are there any uses for untyped unions(w/out a type tag)?

Tags: c, unions, algebraic-data-types

Other then memory casting tricks is there any way to use an untagged union

(a data type that explicitly hold one of a set of types that isn't a tagged union,

ie. one that is forced by the compiler to hold an associated type tag and possibly only allowed by the language to get the value of the proper type)

without an associated type tag in the container that holds it?

Are there any other advantage an untagged union holds over a typed union?

edit: to show what I mean example tagged union in haskell

```
data U = I Int | S String
```

manually tagged union in c

```
enum u_types {INT,STRING};
typedef struct {
    u_types tag;
    union u{
    int i;
    char s[STRING_BUFFER_SIZE];
    } d;
}tagged union;
```

untagged union in c

```
    union u{
    int i;
    char s[STRING_BUFFER_SIZE];
    } d;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. With "untagged"/"untyped", do you mean an union lacking a union tag, `union { int x; };` or an *incomplete type*, for example `union something* x;` where "something" has not yet been declared? The former would be "untagged", it has a formal meaning in the C language. The latter would perhaps be "untyped", but formally there is nothing in C called "untyped", as far as I know.

Comment: I meant a c like union (untyped was a mistake I meant untagged) without an associated tag(usually an enum in a struct in c). As opposed to something like a union ADT in haskell

Comment: enum in a struct?? What has this to do with ADTs?? Now I understand even less. Could you perhaps update your question with a code example?

Comment: an adt (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) in functional languages is a bit like a struct and a bit like union

Comment: Aah no-no ADT is the common acronym for Abstract Data Type, which means something entirely different. An algebraic data type = a  variant. See my answer further below:

Answer (score 9):

One use for untagged unions is to allow easy access to smaller parts of a larger type:

```
union reg_a {
  uint32_t    full;
  struct {    /* little-endian in this example */
    uint16_t  low;
    uint16_t  high;
  } __attribute__((__packed__));
};
union reg_a a;
a.full = 0x12345678; /* set all whole 32-bits */
a.high = 0xffff;      /* change the upper 16-bits */

union pix_rgba {
  uint32_t    pix;    /* to access the whole 32-bit pixel at once */
  struct {
    uint8_t   red;    /* red component only */
    uint8_t   green;  /* green component only */
    uint8_t   blue;   /* blue only */
    uint8_t   alpha;  /* alpha only */
  } __attribute__((__packed__));
};
```

These sorts of uses are not necessarily completely portable though, since they may depend on specific representations of types, endianness, etc.  Still, they're often portable enough that one or two alternate versions will cover all the platforms one cares about, and they can be quite useful.

Untagged unions are also useful when what is stored in the union will be known anyway, even without checking the tag, and you don't want the extra overhead of storing and updating a tag.  Possibly information in another place, that may also serve another purpose, may indicate what kind of data should be in the union -- in which case there's no need tag the union itself.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the tag if you only plan to define one variable, or use it inside a struct.

For example:

```
union
{
  int x;
  int y;
} u;

void test(void)
{
  u.x = 10;
}
```

You only need the tag if you plan to use it in more than one place, if you need to create a pointer to it etc.

*Note:* The answer above assumed that the question was about what the standard calls a *tag*. However, after the answer was given, the question was updated to indicate that the tag in question was an extra type field used to record which of the fields in the union was active.

Answer (score 1):

What you have posted as "manually tagged" is not valid C syntax , I suppose you meant it to be:

```
typedef enum {INT,STRING} u_types;

typedef struct {
    u_types tag;
    union u{
    int i;
    char s[1];
    } d;
}tagged_union;
```

Please note that the formal definition of a struct/union *tag* in C is the name after the struc/union keyword. In your second example, `u` is a *union tag*. This is what had me quite confused.

---

What you describe as "tagged union" is known as a *variant* in computer science: a variable which can hold multiple types. Variants are generally frowned upon in programming in general and in C in particular. They are banned in MISRA-C:2004, rules 18.3 and 18.4.

Languages with support for variants, like VB (and probably Haskell?) typically present then as: this variable can hold anything, but you should be careful with using it, because it is very inefficient.

In C, variants are not only inefficient, they are a safety hazard. MISRA-c recognizes this in rule 18.3:

> For example: a program might try to access data of one type from the location when actually it is storing a value of the other type (e.g. due to an interrupt). The two types of data may align differently in the storage, and encroach upon other data. Therefore the data may not be correctly initialised every time the usage switches. The practice is particularly dangerous in concurrent systems.

---

So the question should rather be, are there any uses for tagged unions (variants)? No, there is not. I haven't used a single one in any C program I have ever written, there is no use for them. Since C has void pointers, there are far better and safer ways in C to create generic data types:

`void ADT_add_generic_type (void* data, some_enum_t type, size_t size);`

Take a look at how the C standard implements the functions qsort() and bsearch() for some good examples of generic C programming (ISO 9899:1999 7.20.5.1):

```
void *bsearch (const void *key, 
               const void *base, 
               size_t nmemb, 
               size_t size,
               int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

> Description The bsearch function searches an array of nmemb objects,
>   the initial element of which is pointed to by base, for an element
>   that matches the object pointed to by key. The size of each element of
>   the array is specified by size.

---

The uses for "untagged" unions are several, however. Data protocols, packing, hardware register access etc etc. See Dmitri's answer for a good example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick:

```
static __attribute__((const, always_inline))
int32_t floatToIntBits(float f) {
    union {
        float value;
        int32_t bits;
    };
    value = f;
    return bits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you have a generic implementation using `void *`, you could use an untagged union instead. Since you are using `void *` the true object type has to be known from context.

This is a maximally portable way to implement a generic datastructure that can store  `union { void *ptr; unsigned x; }` for example (on C platforms where there is no `uintptr_t`).